# how do i prevent CORS and Mixed Content error with my fetch requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

so i have been trying to have my website fetch data from my nodejs/expressjs app, i had the client website receiving data without issue on localhost but as soon as i deployed it on the server i started to get mixed content errors so i proceeded to add https middleware for my expressjs app but then i got CORS errors.

i have set the res.header origin to '*' as well, but it still returned a cors error, im hoping i just overlooked something simple but i feel im a bit out of my depth

and yes i am aware of my jankie auth middleware, i havent gotten to JWT tokens yet, im still a beginner

currently im using a url scheme like

client website 'https://build.mysite.com' fetching with apiUrl='https://api.mysite.com:3502'

and nodejs address 'https://api.mysite.com'

this is the client fetch function

```
import { apiUrl } from "../global-variables.js";

async function getApiNav(target, version = null) {
  // declaring the item to target from the database
  target = `?target=${target}`;
  // declaring the version number if it is passed in arguments
  if (version == null) {
    version = "";
  } else if (typeof version == "number") {
    version = `&version=${version}`;
  }
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/product/nav${target}${version}`);
    const apiRes = await res.json();
    return apiRes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      `There was an error requesting navigation data from mysite.com${error}`
    );
  }
}
export default getApiNav;
```

and this is the main app.js file for the node app

```
// Loading Environment Variables
require("dotenv").config({ path: `/var/www/env/.env` });
require("dotenv").config();
console.log(`*** Using ${process.env.NODE_ENV} Environment Variables ***`);
const {
  DB_CONNECT: Database,
  CORS: corsOrigin,
  DEV_URL: devUrl,
  PORT: port,
  HTTPS_PORT: httpsPort,
  POST_CRED: postPassword,
} = process.env;

// Dependancies
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { NavVersionCheck } = require("./functions/nav/navFunctions");

// Connect to database -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mongoose.connect(
  Database,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  () => {
    console.log("*** Connected to DB ***");
    // Version check and print for database collections
    NavVersionCheck("header", true);
    NavVersionCheck("sideNav", true);
  }
);

// Middleware ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb" }));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", corsOrigin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
});

// Checks the request body for the password so that you can post to the database
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.body.auth = false;
  req.body.password === postPassword
    ? (req.body.auth = true)
    : (req.body.auth = false);
  next();
});

// Import Routes
const NavRoutes = require("./routes/nav/navNavRoutes");
const ContentRoutes = require("./routes/nav/navContentRoutes");
const SpecRoutes = require("./routes/nav/navSpecRoutes");

// Routes --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.use("/nav/nav", navNavRoutes);
app.use("/nav/content", navContentRoutes);
app.use("/nav/spec", navSpecRoutes);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: `this is the root api` });
});

// Port Listeners -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("ERROR ", err);
  }
  console.log(`*** Listening on port ${port} ***`);
});
//
const httpOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "ssl", "cert.pem")),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "ssl", "key.pem")),
};
//
https.createServer(httpOptions, app).listen(httpsPort, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("ERROR ", err);
  }
  console.log(`*** Listening on HTTPS port ${httpsPort} ***`);
});
//
```

and also my nginx routing for this project is

```
server {
    root /var/www/nodejs;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name api.mysite.com www.api.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3500;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}    
server {
    if ($host = www.api.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = api.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name api.mysite.com www.api.mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: have you try to use cors middleware in your node app?
see: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html may this could help

Comment: thanks for the tip but i ended up trying the cors middle ware but after days of smacking myself in the face with my keyboard!!! i finally found the issue,

since i was using nginx proxy pass i didn't need to include the port in the fetch call, its always something simple that gets overlooked lol